# How to create a filter with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm an apprentice in React, i'm studying e practicing but i have a problem, i did want to create a filter for my application.

I have that code:

```js
class Pagination extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      elementsPerPage:3,
      currentPage:0,
      peoples:[
  {id:0, name:"jee"}, 
  {id:1, name:"jiii"}, 
  {id:2, name:"jaa"}, 
  {id:3, name:"joo"}, 
  {id:4, name:"daaa"}, 
  {id:5, name:"hehee"}, 
  {id:6, name:"hoho"}, 
  {id:7, name:"ihihi"}, 
  {id:8, name:"huheue"},
  {id:9, name:"haha"}, 
  {id:10, name:"brbr"}, 
  {id:11, name:"ususauasaua"}]
    };

    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this);
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this);
    this.searchItem = this.searchItem.bind(this);

  }
 

/*  elementsOnScreen () {
 const currentState = this.state;
 return this.state.numbers
  .slice(this.state.currentPage*this.state.elementsPerPage, this.state.currentPage*this.state.elementsPerPage + this.state.elementsPerPage)
  .map(number => (<li>{number}</li>));
}  
 */ 
  
    
  elementsOnScreen () {
 const {elementsPerPage, currentPage, peoples} = this.state;
  
    
 return peoples
  .slice(currentPage*elementsPerPage, currentPage*elementsPerPage + elementsPerPage)
  .map((peoples)=><li>{peoples.name}</li>);
       
       
} 
  
  nextPage () {
     const {elementsPerPage, currentPage, peoples} = this.state;
    
if((currentPage+1) * elementsPerPage < peoples.length){
  this.setState({ currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1 });
    console.log(this.state.currentPage)  
}
  }
  
    previousPage () {
      const { currentPage } = this.state;
      if(currentPage - 1 >= 0){
         this.setState({ currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1 });
      }

  }

  searchItem (){
 
    console.log(this.state.elementsPerPage)
  }

  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input></input>
        <button onClick={this.searchItem}> Search </button>
       <button onClick={this.previousPage}> Previous </button>
       <button onClick={this.nextPage}> Next </button>
       <h1>Names: {this.elementsOnScreen()} </h1>
      <h1>Current Page: {this.state.currentPage}</h1>
      
        </div>
  
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
<Pagination/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

The idea of the filter is: Filter if there were some word or letter equal the typed on input.

**Example:**
I typed letter "a", return the words:

1. "jaa",
2. "daaa",
3. "haha" and
4. "ususauasaua".

Somebody will could help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of `.filter()` in order to get the array of objects which contains that specific letter (in your case its "a") so :

```
peoples.filter(item => item.name.includes("a"))
```

This will return you :

```
peoples:[
  {id:2, name:"jaa"}, 
  {id:4, name:"daaa"}, 
  {id:9, name:"haha"}, 
  {id:11, name:"ususauasaua"}];
```

And then you can chain the `.map()` over the returned array and get the name property :

```
peoples.filter(item => item.name.includes("a")).map(item => item.name);
```

This will return you an array of just names :

```
["jaa", "daaa", "haha", "ususauasaua"]
```

Inside your elementsOnScreen function

```
elementsOnScreen () {
 const { peoples} = this.state;
  return (
    <div> { peoples.filter(item => item.name.includes("a")).map(item => 
    (<li> {item.name}</li>))} 
    </div>
 )
}
```

Now you will get :

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

To avoid this make sure inside your `.map()` give a unique key value to the `<li>`

```
.map(item => (<li key= {item.id}> {item.name}</li>));
```